# The term 'Write-SitecoreDockerWelcome' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function

Tags: docker, powershell

We're trying to init docker on a new dev machine however we're running into issues... it appears that sitecore docker tools is not installing?

The error is

```
Installing SitecoreDockerTools...
Importing SitecoreDockerTools...
C:\sitecore\init.ps1 : The term 'Write-SitecoreDockerWelcome' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function,
script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is
correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ .\init.ps1 -LicenseXmlPath "C:\license\license.xml"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Write-SitecoreDockerWelcome:String) [init.ps1], CommandNotFoundExceptio
   n
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException,init.ps1
```

The script is:

```
Check for Sitecore Gallery
Import-Module PowerShellGet
$SitecoreGallery = Get-PSRepository | Where-Object { $_.SourceLocation -eq "https://sitecore.myget.org/F/sc-powershell/api/v2" }
if (-not $SitecoreGallery) {
    Write-Host "Adding Sitecore PowerShell Gallery..." -ForegroundColor Green 
    Register-PSRepository -Name SitecoreGallery -SourceLocation https://sitecore.myget.org/F/sc-powershell/api/v2 -InstallationPolicy Trusted
    $SitecoreGallery = Get-PSRepository -Name SitecoreGallery
}
# Install and Import SitecoreDockerTools 
$dockerToolsVersion = "10.0.5"
Remove-Module SitecoreDockerTools -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
if (-not (Get-InstalledModule -Name SitecoreDockerTools -RequiredVersion $dockerToolsVersion -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)) {
    Write-Host "Installing SitecoreDockerTools..." -ForegroundColor Green
    Install-Module SitecoreDockerTools -RequiredVersion $dockerToolsVersion -Scope CurrentUser -Repository $SitecoreGallery.Name -AllowClobber
}
Write-Host "Importing SitecoreDockerTools..." -ForegroundColor Green
Import-Module SitecoreDockerTools -RequiredVersion $dockerToolsVersion
Write-SitecoreDockerWelcome <--- Fails here
```

Running each line manually shows no errors, calling `Get-PSRepository` shows `SitecoreGallery` as a trusted source.

Running `Get-InstalledModule` also shows a single `SitecoreDockerTools` under the correct version (This is expected as it's a fresh windows machine).

So everything appears to be installed but the commands are just not found.

Any advice appreciated!

**Edit**

On inspection of our repo, it looks like a commit of our init.ps1 file was downgraded to 10.0.5 from 10.1.4 for the SitecoreDockerTools module

Comment: The module must not be downloading or loading in the script. Do you see errors when this runs?

Comment: I've added full error - nothing else is thrown, very odd... @MichaelWest

Comment: Can you run each line manually in a console and see what happens?

Comment: additional info added @MichaelWest

Comment: please install manually Install-Package SitecoreDockerTools -Version 10.2.7 -Source https://sitecore.myget.org/F/sc-powershell/api/v3/index.json

Comment: hope do you have https://github.com/Sitecore/docker-tools/blob/dev/powershell/src/Public/Write-SitecoreDockerWelcome.ps1

Comment: @SeanT please give a vote if the answer is useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this will help for you

please install Sitecore Docker Tools Manually using below commands

```
Install-Package SitecoreDockerTools -Version 10.1.4 -Source sitecore.myget.org/F/sc-powershell/api/v3/index.json
```

Comment: This wasn't the solution as it's already installed - the problem was it was an older version of SitecoreDockerTools that did not feature all of the module items. If you want to amend the answer I to 10.1.4 as per my edit I will accept

Comment: @SeanT I have edited my answer. Still the issue there